# Change mouse pointer from hand to I

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using gird view which have read write access
using password user can login and on its password he can read or write on the grid view

on grid view i have asp:button i disable it by using grid view's command event

```
protected void gvMemSpb_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int iRow = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(e.Row.RowIndex));
            if (iRow > -1)
            {
                if (Session["Me_Status"].ToString() == "" || Session["Me_Status"].ToString() == "R")
                {

                    e.Row.Cells[3].Enabled = false;
                    e.Row.Cells[4].Enabled = false;
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Enabled = false;
                    lblRWAccess.Text = "This is (read only) Access page";
                }

            }

        }
```

This is how i disable the asp:button on grid view, they get disable,
but the problem is that it is still showing hand icon on it when mouse over those buttons, 
i do not want to show hand pointer on mouse over event i lot search on google but could not find probable solution how to hide the hand pointer pragmatically

```
 {
                    ?//what code i add hear to hide hand pointer 
                    ?
                     ?
                    e.Row.Cells[3].Enabled = false;
                    e.Row.Cells[4].Enabled = false;
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Enabled = false;
                    lblRWAccess.Text = "This is (read only) Access page";
                }
```

Thanks in advance
Vaibhav Deshpande(MCA)

Answer (score 1):

I would use CSS to modify the button's cursor when it is disabled, upon disable you could add a class that changes the cursor from it's default to what you desire and upon enable you remove the class.  CSS would be like

```
nohand { cursor: text; } /* this should change the cursor to the I-bar when added to an html element */
```

Comment: That's Done
Very very thanks
I used the code as follows
                                       
{                   e.Row.Cells[3].Enabled = false;
                    e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "nohand";
                }
               
And declare the css
nohand { cursor: text; }  
in the top 
and i am very very happy that its working fine now
Thank's a Ton